# How can I access current html elements certain property value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my js/jquery code in which I am trying to access the current button that was clicked, with class of delete, and then get the property data-id's value. When I console.log the string that I hope to have it says undefined?
Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).prop("data-id");
    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: try `$(this).attr("data-id");` or `$(this).data("id");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data-*` is an attribute you need to use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

or you can get `data-*` attribute value using **[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
```

Comment: thanks this worked, got the .prop(), and .attr() jquery functions mixed up

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
 var id=  $(this).attr('data-id');
 console.log(id);
})
```

Comment: Sorry it was my spelling mistake I edited it , sorry again

Answer (score 0):

Try the attr() method.

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest would be:

```
$(".delete").on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(id);
});
```